# How to write DRY code when working $(this) and $each for form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some code which enables and disables input and select fields on a series of forms. I have repeated a lot of code and I wanted to know how I would write this in a DRY, scalable way.

I created a Fiddle and and it repeats three times - edit, cancel and save.

```
$(edit).each(function(){

$(this).on('click', function(){ }); });
```

Here is my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/tellmehow/5tcs6f82/9/

I will keep working on this, but if anyone has any pointers or a similar Fiddle, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: You should reduce your code to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, then post the code here. There are vastly more efficient methods of doing what you want, e.g. every form control has a *form* property that references the form it's in, so if you use buttons for buttons (instead of broken links), then `$(this).closest("form")` is simply `this.form`. And if the button is given a name like *saveButton*, then `$(section).find(save).show()` is `$(this.form.saveButton).show()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce your repetition of hide/show/disable etc, by putting your form/button manipulation into a single function like this:

```
function setFormMode($form, mode){
    switch(mode){
        case 'view':
            $form.find('.save-button, .cancel-button').hide();
            $form.find('.edit-button').show();
            $form.find("input, select").prop("disabled", true);
            break;
        case 'edit':
            $form.find('.save-button, .cancel-button').show();
            $form.find('.edit-button').hide();
            $form.find("input, select").prop("disabled", false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Create three "onclick" functions (because, presumably you'll want to do other things as well):

```
function edit_onclick(){
    setFormMode($(this).closest("form"), 'edit');
}

function cancel_onclick(){
    setFormMode($(this).closest("form"), 'view');

    //TODO: Undo changes?
}

function save_onclick(){
    setFormMode($(this).closest("form"), 'view');

    //TODO: Send data to server?
}
```

And then bind:

```
$('.save-button').on('click', save_onclick);
$('.cancel-button').on('click', cancel_onclick);
$('.edit-button').on('click', edit_onclick);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5tcs6f82/10/

Comment: Seamus, this is exactly the response I was looking for. Thank you very much.  By creating a switch mode this removes a lot of the repetition in my code.  I will go on to become a better programmer from this example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like the following. It doesn't use jQuery but demonstrates an alternative approach that adds or removes a class called *hidden* to hide or show the buttons. It also uses event delegation to reduce the number of listeners.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

The following is the main function, it can be more concise if a toggle class function is used.

```
/* If click is from element with class edit-button, hide it and show
 * buttons with class cancel-button or save-button.
 * If click is from element with class cancel-button or save-button,
 * hide them and show button with class edit-button
 */

function toggleButtons(event) {
  var form = this;
  var target = event.target;

  // If the click came from a button with class edit-button, hide it and
  // show the cancel and save buttons, otherwise show the edit button and
  // hide the cancel and show buttons
  if (hasClass(target, ['cancel-button','save-button','edit-button'])) {
    var buttons = form.querySelectorAll('.cancel-button, .save-button, .edit-button');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, function(el) {
      if (hasClass(el, 'hidden')) {
        removeClass(el, 'hidden');
      } else {
        addClass(el, 'hidden');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Instead of adding a listener to each element, just add one listener to each form:

```
window.onload = function() {
  for (var forms=document.forms, i=0, iLen=forms.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Add listener to each form
    forms[i].addEventListener('click', toggleButtons, false);

    // Hide the cancel and save buttons
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(forms[i].querySelectorAll('.cancel-button, .save-button'),
                                 function(el){addClass(el, 'hidden')}
    );
  }
}
```

Some library functions that replace equivalent jQuery

```
// Return true if el has class className
// If className is an array, return true if el has any class in className
function hasClass(el, className) {
  if (typeof className == 'string') {
    className = [className];
  }
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(' + className.join('|') + ')(\\s+|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}

// Add class className to el
function addClass(el, className) {
  var classes;  

  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    classes = el.className.match(/\S+/g) || [];
    classes.push(className);
    el.className = classes.join(' ');
  }
}

// Remove class className from el
function removeClass(el, className) {
  var re;
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)','g');
    classes = el.className.replace(re, ' ').match(/\S+/g);
    el.className = classes.join(' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob this too is a great answer to my question. Both answers have helped me learn to write more efficient code and I'm truly grateful.